# CMake: Combining two projects in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have the following structure of my projects:

---

### Project1/src/samples/*.cpp files

### Project1/src/Project2/examples/*.cc and *.h files

### Project1/src/Project2/lib/*.c , *.h , *.o and a .la files

The .la file is created using the *.c source files in the lib folder of Project2 using libtool.

I need to link the .la file in one of the cpp files present in the 
**Project1/src/samples/**.

I have already tried the following in CmakeLists.txt present in **Project1/src/samples**:
`add_executable(source_file source_file.cpp)
target_link_library(source_file ${LOCATION_OF_.LA_FILE})`

CMakeLists.txt is present in

1. Project1/
2. Project1/src
3. Project1/src/samples
4. Project1/src/Project2/
5. Project1/src/Project2/examples
6. Project1/src/Project2/lib

Every time I make the Project1's *source_file* I get the following linker error "`Undefined reference to fun()`"
where, fun() is defined in one of the *c* files present in **Project1/src/Project2/lib/.**

Any ideas what is the problem and how to link the .la of Project2 in Project1. Or is there a way I can include the *.c files from Project2/lib's folder in the CMakeLists.txt of Project1's samples folder?

Comment: You link C++ to C library, do you use `extern "C"` around `#include "*.h"` files?

Comment: Yes the .h files storing the declaration of the function has extern "C" before it.

Comment: 1) You should creat a target for Project2/lib then link Project1/sample to it. 2) not sure Project1/src/CMakeLists.txt is needed or i would put sample outside of src IMHO

Comment: Project2 .la is for libtool so not needed IMHO also why you do have .a and .c/.h ? if it is a precompiled version of project2/lib then create an imported target otherwise remove it and just use .h/.c aka build from source